# Clover + Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, clover

Has any of you managed to generate Clover reports successfully for web-apps on Tomcat or any other web server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's Atlassian's documentation that helped me get it set up:

- [About distributed per-test coverage](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/About+Distributed+Per-Test+Coverage)
- [Using a flush policy](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Using+a+Flush+Policy)

Basically, you add minor configuration to your ant or maven setup before compiling and before running tests and then run your coverage as usual.